# replace substring defined by start and end index points?

Tags: java, eclipse, string, indexing, substring

I am working with this piece of code:

```
start = str.indexOf('<');
finish = str.indexOf('>');
between = str.substring(start + 1, finish);
replacement = str.substring(start, finish + 1);
System.out.println(between + " " + replacement); //for debug purposes
forreplacement = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a " + between);
System.out.println(forreplacement); //for debug purposes
counter = counter - 1;
```

where "str" is the String that is being worked with. How do I replace the substring "replacement" with the string "forreplacement" (what is entered into the popup box) within the string str?

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand. Please give an expected input-output.

Comment: Can you provide the inputs and ouputs strings?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that is what you want but maybe take part before `start`, add `forreplacemeent` and after that add part after `finish` like

```
String result = str.substring(0, start)+forreplacement+str.substring(finish+1);
```

Or if you want to replace all occurrences of `replacement` with `forreplacement` you can also use

```
String result = str.replace(replacement, forreplacement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. If you want to replace, you can do something like-

```
String str = "Hello World!";
String replacement = "World";
String stringToReplaceWith = "Earth";

str = str.replace(replacement, stringToReplaceWith);

System.out.println(str); // This prints Hello Earth!
```